# Odd behavior with margin & width

Tags: css

I have a div element that I had set to 75% width of the entire body:

```
 ____________
|            |
|[mydiv..]   |
|            |
|            |
|____________|
```

Then I centered it with `margin: 0 auto;`, but the results looked like this:

```
 ____________
|            |
|[mydiv.....]|
|            |
|            |
|____________|
```

It was centered, but only because the width, for some reason, seems to be close to 100% now.

This is a print stylesheet, so I'm only able to see the result with Chrome Print Preview (unless anyone knows how to force an alternate stylesheet on a rendered webpage...), therefore I can't use Firebug to check on everything.

Any help?

Comment: To solve problem 1, why not set it as the main stylesheet until you are done testing?

Comment: It has to be something else in your CSS causing it, because this works fine: **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjDgL/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think your page gets scaled automatically to the paper size so I´m not sure that setting a width and auto margins will have any effect.

As a test you could try to set the width to `auto` and the margins to `0 12.5%` or use a wrapper element.